# How to fill a spinner with content?

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

guys I'm very new to the Java word, but i share part of the knowledge because of my c# background, anyways i started developing for android and I'm running into a few snags like the following.

I usually program very OOP so i made all my objects and now i got a very common `public class User` with things like:

```
public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
```

and many other properties in it. Also i have a `class UserHelper` 
where i have a populated array with all the users been pulled by the queries in the Helper

> public ArrayList< User > getCurrentUsers() {         return currentUsers;
>     }

well... the thing is, i want to be able to populate a spinner with a the value returned from getFirstName as the Display and getId obviously as the Id. I know exactly how to do this in C# but i been trying to fight with Cursors and doing some reading around but nothing, so i figured that it would be an interesting question.

ANYONE CAN SHOW ME HOW TO DO IT PLEASE?

Comment: Try referring to the <a href="http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html">user docs.</a> They are so helpful, it's almost sensical.

Comment: You are right, the answer was there, and I have been trough those documents so many times (that is how i learned what i know so far) I cannot even count. But you know sometimes when you are on a deadline you miss the stupid stuff like this (i was just passing the wrong type to the ArrayAdapter), anyways sometimes you need to save the saracsm, because i actually read the thing and was just stuck, i supposed it never happened to you??

Comment: Sorry, for yelling, explanation below...
BTW you yelling too...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Alex look this examples

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.